# Do I / we really have to learn testing when learning ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, ruby-on-rails-4, railstutorial.org

I'm very new to rails and have been following Ruby on Rails Tutorial book by Michael Hartl these days. I feel like testing is a really important thing for developing rails applications since the testing part covers about half of the entire book. But the more I read the book the more overwhelmed I felt about those code because sometimes I would have to spend so much time learning/ figuring out the test code before I can actually move on to the real code for the application. So my question is, is it really necessary to learn rails and its testing at the same time or it is okay for me to learn the rails basics first and maybe buy a rails testing book to learn it in particular after I get familiar with everything about rails so that I will not be too overwhelmed and I could spend more time focusing on the features using rails. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Actually, the book itself [answers your question](http://www.railstutorial.org/book/static_pages#sec-first_tests):**

> It’s important to understand that TDD is not always the right tool for
>   the job: there’s no reason to dogmatically insist that tests always
>   should be written first, that they should cover every single feature,
>   or that there should necessarily be any tests at all. For example,
>   when you aren’t at all sure how to solve a given programming problem,
>   it’s often useful to skip the tests and write only application code,
>   just to get a sense of what the solution will look like. (In the
>   language of Extreme Programming (XP), this exploratory step is called
>   a spike.) Once you see the general shape of the solution, you can then
>   use TDD to implement a more polished version.

Comment: Nice quote. I am self taught and testing is not something that came naturally. I now see the enormous value that it has, but writing coverage tests for every possible function still seems excessive.

Comment: Thank you for the quote that I didn't pay much attention to. I'm also new to this community so I didn't know opinion-based questions are not recommended in here. Anyway your answer was helpful :)